# C ++, OpenCV : Cannot include imgproc library for Cvtcolor function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv and I want to use CvtColor function when I write

```
<#include opencv2/imgproc/imgproc2410.hpp>
```

it says Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/imgproc/imgproc2410.hpp': No such file or directory

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such a file called:

```
<#include opencv2/imgproc/imgproc2410.hpp>
```

replace it with

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```